# What equivalents are there to TortoiseSVN, on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, tortoisesvn, version-control

I am using a MacBook Pro running Mac OS X 10.5. I am new to this development environment, and previously worked on Windows.

I find there is no TortoiseSVN for Mac PC, and I am wondering any alternative (better free and easy to use GUI tools) tools for Mac?

Comment: How is this not constructive?!

Comment: How is this NOT CONSTRUCTIVE? It' the single most popular SVN client for Windows, and it doesn't exist for Mac.

Comment: In current terminology, this would be closed as off-topic: tool recommendation. It still shouldn't be reopened.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have a look at this archived question: [TortoiseSVN for Mac?](http://web.archive.org/web/20140618042642/http://superuser.com/questions/58225/tortoisesvn-for-mac) at superuser. (Original question was removed, so only archive remains.)

Have a look at this page for more likely up to date alternatives to TortoiseSVN for Mac: [Alternative to: TortoiseSVN](http://alternativeto.net/software/tortoisesvn/?platform=mac)

Comment: Link is dead...

Comment: The new one is dead as well...

Comment: @dev_in_prog do you still have trouble with the new link? I can't replicate your issue.

Answer (score 7):

My previous version of this answer had links, that kept becoming dead.
So, I've pointed it to the internet archive to preserve the original answer.

[Subversion client releases for Windows and Macintosh](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306112404/https://blog.assembla.com/AssemblaBlog/tabid/12618/bid/84534/Subversion-client-releases-for-Windows-and-Macintosh.aspx)

[Wiki - Subversion clients comparison table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients)

Comment: The link above no longer works. Links I managed to dig out:  

_Blog:_  
https://blog.assembla.com/AssemblaBlog/tabid/12618/bid/84534/Subversion-client-releases-for-Windows-and-Macintosh.aspx  

_Download:_  
https://app.assembla.com/spaces/macintosh-svn-client/wiki/_EasySVN_Mac_OSX_Beta

*Disclaimer: I haven't tried it so cannot recommend*

Comment: the updated link is dead

Comment: updated to use the internet archives version, due to frequency of links braking

Answer (score 4):

i use "Versions", quite easy, but not free .

[http://versionsapp.com/](http://versionsapp.com)

Answer (score 3):

I use svnX (http://code.google.com/p/svnx/downloads/list), it is free and usable, but not as user friendly as tortoise. It shows you the review before commit with diff for every file... but sometimes I still had to go to command line to fix some things

Comment: The link given in this answer is out-of-date, you can download svnX 2.0 from this page: https://code.google.com/p/svnx/wiki/Changes

Comment: Here's a direct link to downloads (version in previous comment is out of date):   https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/svnx/html/Downloads.html