# Use eclipse as svn client

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Running OSX.

I have used eclipse for years as a Java developer.  I am now messing with all kinds of new technologies but still find myself using svn (don't ask its not my descision).  Anyways I don't really like SVN command line as I find it almost impossible to sort through merge conflicts.

With that I was thinking about using eclipse (w/ subclipse plugin) as my SVN client whenever I need to do SVN type things.  The one problem that I have found is that eclipse loves to create a .project file.  I would never want to check this in as no one else is using eclipse.  I know that I can add it to svn:ignore, but that has to actually commit that ignore to SVN as well, which I do not want to do either.

Anyway to create eclipse projects without the .project file.  I know sounds dumb because I am sure that eclipse needs the .project file for all its projects.  Would be nice just to create an SVN project (not Java project) and have eclipse leave off any other crap.

ideas?

Comment: subversion has a config file that you can add global ignores to.  where that lives depends on your os.  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694900/global-ignores-for-svn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create an Eclipse project without the `.project` file (at least none that I know of), but you can tell Eclipse which files to ignore, as well.

Just go to *Preferences -> Team -> Ignored Resources* and add the pattern `.project`.

This setting is purely Eclipse-internal and does neither affect your global svn-ignores (defined in `~/.subversion/config`) nor will it add any files to the repository.

Also, when checking out folders from SVN using Eclipse, make sure to create a *General Project*, not a *Java Project*, so the `.project` file is the only file Eclipse creates.

Answer (score 0):

`.project` is actually not the only file that will be generated - depending on the "project natures" you add to a project.
To really separate the project from the source folders, you'll have to create the project in a separate folder - say the workspace - remove the original source folder and **add the source folders as external links** - see: Project Settings/Java Build Path/Source.

Comment: I am not building Java so I have no need for linking in source.  Again I just want to use Eclipse to do SVN stuff, commit, merge, etc.

Comment: OK then - but it doesn't seem possible to link other folders in a simple project - or at least I don't know how to do that. You can simply create a Java-Project anyway and link source folders without adding any java files to them. There is no need to do so. But Java projects are probably the most common projects used in eclipse and probably have the most features - including that linking of source folders. Another possibility would be to use something like [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.net/). Why bother with eclipse then - where maybe not even all svn-operations are supported?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am on OSX.  I would love a free tool like tortisesvn on OSX but no such luck.  Xcode's SVN tools are awful and there are only a couple free options that are not real good either.

Comment: Probably have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817260/what-equivalents-are-there-to-tortoisesvn-on-mac-osx) - otherwise you'll have to live with eclipse not being perfect. I don't know of any more options as - in the other answer - set the ignored resources - or - as in my answer - try to link your svn-directories to the project directory at another location.